# Subjunctive in if clause

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives, grammar-myths

I have a question about the use of the subjunctive in if clauses.
I usually use grammarly as a grammar checker and ran into following problem:

I wrote: If he stay at home, he would die.

Grammarly corrects me to: If he stay**s** at home, he would die.

I remember that I learned in school to use the simple present/past for if clauses (depending on how likely a condition is).

But then, you say "If I were you", not "If I was you", which is clearly subjunctive.

Doesn't that mean the subjunctive form would be grammatically preferable to the simple present? So "stay" is correct, while "stays" isn't?

Or where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the English of three hundred years ago, *If he stay at home* would be grammatical. But the so-called 'present subjunctive' (which is always the same as the base form) is only used today in a few set phrases (such as "long live ..."), and (for some speakers) after verbs like *command* and *resolve*. It is obsolete to use it after *if*.

However, I find Grammarly's suggestion very odd - I would say, wrong.

In modern English, you can either use the simple present, if the possibility is quite open whether it happens or not:

> If he stays at home, he will die.

Or you can use the past, for a more hypothetical possibility:

> If he stayed at home, he would die.

(Historically, this is the 'past subjunctive', but for every verb in the language except one, it is the same as the simple past. *Were* is the only exception, and not all speakers use it anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree with you on the simple present/will vs. simple past/would part. Can you give an example for the use of the present subjunctive with *command* or *resolve*?

Comment: "They commanded that she leave". And especially in the context of committees and official business: "The committee resolved that the matter be referred to the relevant officer". Not everybody uses this: many would say "should be". But it's still current in an "official" register, particularly in North America

Comment: Intuitively, I'd use "shall be": "The committee resolves that the matter shall be referred to the relevant officer"

Comment: @h345k34cr: I meant to say "resolved", and edited it - apparently after you posted your comment.