# Subjunctive mood in Present tense

Tags: subjunctives, present-subjunctive

I have recently learned about subjunctive mood. I am very confused about it. Consider these sentences

> *If he were driving, we would have reached the town by now.*

> *If he were to drive, we would reach the town by now.*

Rule : The subjunctive mood of the verb to be is be in the present tense and were in the past tense, regardless of what the subject is.

Question 1: Both these sentences are in past; and I want to know what will be a present form of such a sentence? Please include an example from your side to explain hypothetical condition in present.

If he be driving, If he be to drive both sound incorrect to my ears. So please tell me its possible present form.

Question 2 : I think, the second verb or main verb in a subjunctive mood sentence can be in its base form or Verb + ing and it can never be past participle. Is it correct?

Question 3 : How to change *to be* to *be*?

Comment: I don't understand Q3. I think we can change "to be" to "be" by dropping the "to".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subjunctive in if clause](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/180615/subjunctive-in-if-clause)

Comment: Your sentences are _not_ in the past. _If he were driving_ imagines that he is driving now, and _If he were to drive_ imagines him taking over the driving from whoever is at the wheel now. Also, you can't say _we would reach the town by now_ -- it's either _we would have reached it by now_ or _we would reach it sooner_.

Comment: So would this sentence be correct : The situation demands he be in the room right now.